# How to format old PC?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, formatting, desktop-computer

I have to format an old IBM PC to give it away, before I leave tomorrow.
There is no installation CD. I tried to plug a bootable USB drive, but since this is an old system the BIOS won't let me boot from USB. I have no empty or rewritable CDs. I only have a laptop with me so there is no way of plugging the HDD to the laptop.
How do I properly empty the HDD? I don't need the OS.
Thank you :D

Comment: Is removing the HDD before giving it away an option?

Comment: What is the current OS. And how clean? Wiping the MBR with DD might be sufficient to make it clain it is empty. Properly clean (data actually wiped) is much harder unless you can boot from something else. Either CD, USB, Network, ...

Comment: Also, what is the laptop running? If it is Linux or BSD you can plug the laptop drive into the desktop, boot from that and wipe the old drive. (make sure you select the right one!). If it is windows that do not try this. It probably will not boot on different hardware.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, yes removing the HDD is an option, I just wanted to make sure there were no alternatives.

Comment: @Hennes, the desktop is running Windows XP. Could you please explain the thing of wiping the MBR with DD?  The laptop is an Hackintosh. I already thought of it, I already have an Ubuntu live USB so it is easy to partition the drive and install the new system. The problem is that the desktop does not have SATA connections :/

Comment: I never tried to boot via the network. I'll check if the motherboard supports network boot and eventually see how to do it.

Comment: Networek boot is called PXE. Setting it on the computer you want to boot from should be trivial. Setting up another PC (your laptop) to provide an image is less trivial.  As for potentially even easier (not tested). On XP. startm, run, diskpart, select disk 1, clean. Done.  Not wiped, but disk is now marked as clean. Getting to the data will not de done accidentally.

Comment: from command line cipher /w:c will write over all 'empty' sectors 3 times so if you delete everything you don't want to be 'found', you don't need to change any boot settings

Comment: Can you actually boot into whatever is on the harddisk and format the drive from there?

Comment: @LPChip, yes. I was thinking, I could install Ubuntu on a new partition in the laptop, make a new partition on the desktop HDD, dump everything that is on the new partition on the laptop to an USB drive then copy to the new partition on the desktop via XP. It is not the most straight forward way, but it should work. The question is Will the bootloader let me select the right partition?

Comment: Network or PXE boot is not an option in the BIOS.

Comment: If you can get your hands on a Linux Live CD or a copy of DBAN from another person then you can securely wipe the disk. It sounds like you are quite knowledgeable in computers though so I am going to guess that ultimately you will remove the HDD and take it with you so that you can securely erase it later.